# log4php: [LoggerAppenderFile:default]: Null value given for 'file' property. Expected a string. Property not changed

Tags: php, laravel-5.5, log4php

I install Log4php according to this url [i3ehrang/logger4php][1] [1]: https://packagist.org/packages/i3ehrang/logger4php
I am getting error

> log4php: [LoggerAppenderFile:default]: Null value given for 'file' property. Expected a string. Property not changed.

This is my code

```
use Logger4php;
class loggerController extends Controller
{
  public function showLogger() {    
    $this->log = Logger4php::getLogger(__CLASS__);
    $this->log->info("We have liftoff.");
 }
}
```

i am using laravel5.5 and php 7.1.9.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this.

```
$this->log = new Logger4php();
$this->log->info("We have liftoff.");
```

Comment: error displays
"Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Call to undefined method I3ehrang\Logger4php\Facades\Logger4php::info()"